# Filtering all field values per row

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a table called `'sample'`. Based on which algorithm is used, each sample may have different field (property) names.

I need to be able to retrieve all samples which have field values that contain/match a user filter value.

So for instance, if a sample has the following properties:

example 1: `"name", "gender", "state"`

and another had properties:

example 2: `"name", "gender", "rate"`

and there would be thousands of such samples with more variation.

If a user looking at a table with a set of samples from the second example above (`"name", "gender", "rate"`) and used a filter "foo", I need to query the table "sample" for all rows where any of the property's values contained/matched "foo" where value could be "foobar".

If they were looking at a set of samples that had the properties that example 1 has (`"name", "gender", "state"`), then I need to do the same, however, I cannot hard code the properties of either.

In SQL I would get the field names and dynamically build a SQL query string but with REQL object DOT notation, I am struggling with how to do it.

Comment: Your question implies that a user will be looking at a subset that has one set of properties or the other, but not a combination. Is that true? If so, could you use whatever is creating that subset to get the list of properties to test?

Comment: @ebbishop Yes there is only one search/filter criteria used by the user. There is a single search bar for the table from which the value is sent to the server to retrieve based on this filter all rows where all fields from the table are filtered cross. In addition, the data forms into batches where each batch would have some fields named differently, so hard coding are not possible and field retrieval and values based on filtering of values is required.

Comment: I can get the field names (keys) and their values (values), but I have not found how to use the values() return with a match(). If I use contains() it tells me its not a string and when I do not use contains() it tells me its not string but a sequence....I am missing something.